# Composite C1 - Redirect old .php links to new URL's

Tags: c1-cms

I have just created a new website in Composite C1.

I need to redirect some old URL's - mainly blog URLs - like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/en/news/news.php?b=68

to the new format:
http://mydomain.com/en/Blog/2013/04/30/Friendly-Article-Name

There are about 100 links to redirect.

As they are .php links I can't use 'URL Remapping' - explained here:
http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/URL-Remapping

I also found this article on it - which didn't help much:
http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/308879

I have found this on the Legacy URL Handler. It says I can manually setup redirects by editing  /App_Data/LegacyUrlMappings.xml - however this file does not exist. If I create it, it doesn't redirect.

I don't want to have to install PHP on my server.

What's the simplest way to do this - ideally within the C1 CMS web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by creating /App_Data/LegacyUrlMappings.xml  - in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Mappings>
  <Mapping OldPath="/poo.php" NewPath="/en/blog" /> 
  <Mapping OldPath="/Omnicorp/Test/Forms" NewPath="/page(41328915-3f56-423f-ab8d-157ddc9c8af8)" /> 
</Mappings>
```

Comment: Along with Legacy URL Handler, you can also take a look at a recent add-on by the community: http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/CphCloud.Packages.UrlAlias

Comment: Neither of these world reliably with php links I've found for some strange reason - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and I haven't been able to work out when. Possibly conflicts with MVC Player?!

Comment: I have moved this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236888/composite-c1-url-aliases-redirecting-urls-with-querystring